# Overriding a generic method by a generic one in Java

Tags: java, generics

Angelica Langer says in her FAQ about generics (see [Technicalities.FAQ822](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ822)):

> If the methods have type parameters with different bounds , then they
>   do not override, because the methods have signatures that are not
>   override-equivalent.  Remember, the type parameter bounds are part of
>   a generic method's signature.
>
> Example (of generic subtype methods overloading generic supertype
>   methods; not recommended):
>
> ```java
> class Super {
>    public <T> void set( T arg) { ... }
>    public <T> T get() { ... }
> }
> class Sub extends Super {
>    public <S extends Number > void set( S arg) { ... } // overloads
>    public <S extends Number > S get() { ... }         // overloads
> }
> ```

I don't understand why the `get` method is overloaded in class `Sub`. For what I know it should be a compile time error because `get` has the same signature in both `Sub` and `Super` (the return type is not part of it).

What confuse me even more is that the IDE I'm using to test the code (IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3) highlights `get` in `Sub` as a compilation error with the next message:

> 'get()' in 'Sub' clashes with 'get()' in 'Super'; both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.

But when I run the program it compiles and executes without problems. I suppose there is some kind of bug in IntelliJ when it analyzes the code, and what is correct is what Angelica tells in her FAQ. But I can't catch the point.

Comment: In Eclipse you can set the built-in compiler to be stricter and treat certain conditions as errors (like assignment to self or accessing a static method through an instance). I suppose the same can be done in IDEA too.

Comment: What the problem turns out to be is that the type-parameter of the overridden method doesn't have the same bounds like the type-parameter of the method from the super class.

Comment: As said in the post you cite, _the type parameter bounds are part of a generic method's signature_. So `<T> T get()` and `<S extends Number > S get()` have different signatures. The name clash is still bad, so that's way the poster tell it is _not recommended_

Comment: Kocko's answer basically concludes that the signature collides and hence the error, but shouldn't that make it a valid override then? And, if type parameter bounds are part of the signature then they're different and hence shouldn't it be a valid overload then? I'd like an answer/comment on what's making the compiler say, "it's neither an overload, nor an override and hence an error."

Comment: @RaviThapliyal turns out that in Java7 http://ideone.com/3Oiunb it compiles, while in Java8 it doesn't http://ideone.com/ikOwbm

Comment: [Here's](http://vanillajava.blogspot.in/2011/02/with-generics-return-type-is-part-of.html?_escaped_fragment_#!) a very good post by @PeterLawrey that demonstrates with decompiled code that this worked in Oracle JDK 6 too. He later updates that it doesn't work with Oracle JDK 7 anymore.

Comment: What makes matter worse is that if `Super` had a `public Object get()` and `Sub` had a `public Number get()`, it would be a valid override.

Comment: @biziclop That's a perfectly valid override. The overriding method's return type can be co-variant (subtype) of the overridden method's return type.

Comment: Exactly. With generics though it makes sense that this isn't valid. Imagine this: `Super foo = new Sub(); String bar = foo.<String>get();`. From the caller's point of view this should be fine. From the callee's point of view this is invalid since `Sub.<T>get()` can only accept `T extends Number` and not `String`.

Comment: @biziclop nope, http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ824 _Although the erasures of the subtype methods have signatures that are identical to the supertype methods' signatures the respective signatures are not override-equivalent.  The override-equivalence only holds when the subtype method's signature is identical to the erasure of the supertype method's signature, but not vice versa. _

Comment: @guido I meant without generics. In a non-generic method narrowing the return type of the overridden method is valid. (And has been since Java 5.)

Comment: @biziclop ah ok sorry; with generics, the same applies only if it is narrowing; so that `Super`.`Object get()` will not clash with `Sub`.`<S extends Number>get()` but will clash with `Sub`.`<S>get()`

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your comments, but it's still not clear why the `get` method in `Sub` class _overloads_ the same method in `Super`.  
  
@biziclop: The buil-in compiler options in IntelliJ seems to be in File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections, but I have to play with them to find the correct one to disable this error (just to know it).  

@guido: I didn't know https:\\ideone.com. I have saved this page to test my code.

Comment: @Bleyder why they do overload and not override? because their method signature is different. Why is the signature different? Because in case of generic methods, it contains the method name, the arguments, _and_ the type parameter. Why it does not compile in Java8? I have no idea! I think for the changes on the compiler inferring types

Answer (score 1):

According to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2), method signature does not include return type but only the method name and the type of its parameters. This means when compiling Super and Sub, a compile error should return as Sub.get() has the same erasure as Super.get() but neither overrides nor overloads Super.get(). It cannot override because the bounded type X extends Number is not a subtype of the type X, and it cannot overload because the return type is not part of a method signature. Sub.set overloads Super.set in this case.

As to why you can compile and run it. If you are running Java 6, then there is a known [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321706) in Java 6 that would compile Super and Sub. In Java 7 this is fixed and would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the erasure of  `public <S extends Number> S get()`  is not same or covariant that of `public <T> T get()`.

This compiles and runs:

```
class B {
    public <T> T get() {
        return null;
    }

}

class A extends B {
    @Override
    public <S> S get() {
        return null;
    }
```

This doesn't:

```
class B {
        public <T> T get() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    class A extends B {
        @Override
        public <S extends Number> S get() {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: That's correct. The first code compiles and runs, and the second one doesn't because you're using the `@Override` annotation in `get`. I know for Angelika Langer's FAQ that it is being overloaded, not overridden. What I don't understand is _why_.

Comment: @Bleyder Because `S` and `T` are input parameters.

Comment: @biziclop `S` and `T` are input parameters in _both_ examples. However, in the second one it's a compile-time error because `B` is not overriding method `get`... it's overloading! Why is it that way? How can `B` in the second example overload and not override?

Comment: That's exactly because `S` and `T` are input parameters and you can't narrow the type of an input parameter when you override a method. As I already pointed it out with this example: `Super foo = new Sub(); String bar = foo.<String>get();`. If `Sub.get()` was an override of `Super.get()`, you'd set `S` to type `String`, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Why it is overloading instead of overriding is because the compiler does not see it as override-equivalent. Further into Angelika Langer's FAQ you see it discussing about why overriding a method not as expected.

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ051

To summarize, the methods have the same have the same names and parameters but based on the generic subtype are defined as different. Even with the override annotation, the compiler sees it as an overloaded method. In using generics, there is an added layer to a method, where the generic type applies as part of the method which can uniquely define it.